# PHP / MySQL price matrix form validation

Tags: php, mysql, validation, mysqli

Im sure the solution is fairly simple, my brain however doesn’t appear to be in a right state of mind today. I have a MySQL table storing a pricing matrix of my products.

```
ID     PRODUCT     MINIMUM     PRICE
1      1           2           15
2      1           4           12
3      1           6           10
```

So a quick explanation, for the product with the id 1, if the customer has a minimum quantity of 2 in their shopping basket the price of each item is bought down to £15. If the user then puts another 2 products In their basket the price of each with be decreased to £12.

THE PROBLEM: I need a way of validating a new price tier each time one is added. So if someone wants to add a new tier of:

```
ID     PRODUCT     MINIMUM     PRICE
4      1           3           16
```

This shouldn’t be allowed as in this case the price of each item would increase if the user chooses to purchase three items rather than two. So I need to ensure that prices entered are decreasing as the quantity increases based on values already in the database.

```
$query = 'select id,minimum,price from `cat.tier_price` where product = %d order by minimum asc;';
$query = sprintf($query, (int)$identity);
if(!$return = $db->query($query)){
    echo 'MySQL error!';
}else{
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $price = $_POST['quantity'];

    if($return->num_row){
        while($tier = $return->fetch_object){

        }
    }
}
```

If I haven’t made this clear enough please do say. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [for validating min. 3] Get existing minimum lower than 3 (here: 2) and check if given price is less than the one related to here min. 2 (=15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done by a simple function:

```
function validateTier($productId, $minimum, $price) {
    // check if the new tier is not higher price for higher minimum
    $query = 'SELECT 1 AS exists FROM `cat.tier_price` WHERE `product` = {$productId} AND `minimum` < {$minimum} AND `price` > {$price} ORDER BY `minimum` DESC LIMIT 1';
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

    if(isset($result['exists']) && $result['exists']) {
        // check if the new tier is not lower price for lower minimum
        $query = 'SELECT 1 AS exists FROM `cat.tier_price` WHERE `product` = {$productId} AND `minimum` > {$minimum} AND `price` < {$price} ORDER BY `minimum` ASC LIMIT 1';
        $res2 = mysql_query($query);
        $result2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);

        if(isset($result2['exists']) && $result2['exists']) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You then call this function whenever a new tier should be added. The function tries to select exactly one record where minimum is lower than the one being inserted and the price is higher then the one being inserted. If this query succeeds it will return 1 (considered as true) and this means that the new tear might be inserted. Otherwise the FALSE will be returned which means that the new tier is incorrect.

But I think this should also do a trick (and is more simple):

```
function validateTier($productId, $minimum, $price) {
    // check if the new tier is not higher price for higher minimum
    $query = 'SELECT 1 AS exists FROM `cat.tier_price` WHERE `product` = {$productId} AND ((`minimum` < {$minimum} AND `price` > {$price}) OR (`minimum` > {$minimum} AND `price` < {$price})) LIMIT 1';
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

    if(isset($result['exists']) && $result['exists']) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Please, let me know if this also works.

Comment: Cheers for this, this works with "3,16". however if i attempt "3,11" this should also not be allowed the price is lower than the price for a minimum of 4 products? apologies I didn't mention this above that's my mistake.

Comment: @Adam I edited the function, now it shouldn't allow neither the lower price with lower minimum than one already in the tiers...

Comment: Thank you to everyone I have never seen such a brilliant set of responses to a question. My brain has warmed up a little now, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For data validation of this sort, you should probably use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) that raises an error (e.g. by calling a non-existent procedure) on invalid data before the operation completes; as such, MySQL would abort any attempt to insert invalid data:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE INSERT ON tier_price FOR EACH ROW
  IF (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   tier_price
    WHERE  product = NEW.product
       AND (
              (minimum > NEW.minimum AND price > NEW.price)
           OR (minimum < NEW.minimum AND price < NEW.price)
       )
  ) > 0 THEN
    CALL raise_error;
  END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

If records in `tier_price` might also get updated, you'll probably want a similar trigger `BEFORE UPDATE` too.

Comment: This is an interesting approach that I haven’t considered using before. I’m currently getting the error:
Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Comment: @Adam: That'll teach me for trying to over-optimise.  See my rolled-back version above.

Comment: Thank you to everyone I have never seen such a brilliant set of responses to a question. My brain has warmed up a little now, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it the other way around. It will handle the case when there in no entry in the price_matrix table for a given product_id.

```
    set @product_id := 1;
    set @minimum :=3;
    set @price :=16;

    select count(*) as count from price_matrix where product_id = @product_id and 
    (
        ( minimum > @minimum and price > @price )
        or 
        ( minimum < @minimum and price < @price ) 
    )

   If count > 0:
       This entry is not permitted
   else :
       Permitted
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone I have never seen such a brilliant set of responses to a question. My brain has warmed up a little now, much appreciated.